# Laravel: How can I have the same page in two different languages?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, locale, multilingual

Each page I create must have an english and french version. I want to have two flags in my header and when I click on the US/UK flag I get the english version and my clicking the french flag, I get the french version (pretty much the same as the `polylang` plugin in WordPress).

I know about locales in Laravel. But what I need is, that each view has it's counterpart. For example I have `views/welcome_en.blade.php` and `view/welcome_fr.blade.php` - what I want is that when someone opens the corresponding route `example.com/welcome`, the corresponding counterpart url `example.com/fr/welcome` is passed with that view.

My question is: How can I build the same multilingual Laravel as `Polylang` offers in WordPress by just simple clicking a flag and changing the whole view with it's corresponding counterpart (getting the counterpart link back)?

Comment: Read this: https://medium.com/@Oriechinedu/laravel-localization-made-simple-8ee4a34731e7

Comment: @TahaPaksu thank you, but this is about string translation. What I need is passing a different view depending on the locale, or pass the correct corresponding counterpart URL, that shows up in the flags in order to route to a different view. Only with string translation, I will need to translate thousands of strings.

Comment: Ok, did you try `return view("welcome_".\App::getLocale())` isn't it working?

Comment: Also this can help with the url redirection: https://laraveldaily.com/multi-language-routes-and-locales-with-auth/

Comment: I would use an existing package such as https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization.

Comment: And what about the URL? How can I switch from `example.com/morning` to `example.com/fr/demain`?

Comment: rather changing route just change blade template name